# Problem with 'that' clause

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> It shames us as a nation that a freedom fighter has to scrape a living singing on the streets in his twilight years.

In the above sentence, what is the function of the *that* clause?? Is [that a freedom fighter..... years] a objective complement of us(object) here?

Answer (score 2):

> *It shames us as a nation that a freedom fighter has to scrape a living*
> *singing on the streets in his twilight years*.

No: the *that* clause is not an objective complement.

This is an extraposition construction where the dummy pronoun "it" is subject and the *that* clause is an extraposed subject;  the extraposed element doesn’t give the meaning (reference) of "it" but serves simply as a semantic argument of the VP.

The non-extraposed counterpart would be:

*That a freedom fighter has to scrape a living singing on the streets in his twilight years shames us as a nation.*